# Program starts but does nothing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit

One of our users is trying to run our (open source) [software](http://appleseedhq.net/) on his Windows 7 64-bit machine at his work.

Unfortunately, neither the GUI version nor the command line version of the program run on his machine. The program appears to start but doesn't do anything, and the GUI version does not even open a window.

I don't think the process actually goes very far. Here are Process Explorer views of the process' threads on his and my machine:

On his Windows 7 machine:

[image: Process' threads on Windows 7]

On my Windows 10 machine:

[image: Process' threads on Windows 10]

Our software was built with Visual Studio 2013 in 64-bit mode. The MSVC runtime is included. It has been working for years, probably on a variety of machines.

What's possibly going on?

I'm happy to add the required details.

Update 1: I have Process Monitor traces (*.pml files) for both machines, but while I know how to interpret them, I'm not sure what conclusions I can draw from them. Anyone interested in having a look? I'm a bit hesitant to post them here as I suspect they could contain sensitive information.

Update 2: The problem is reproducible on all Windows 7 machines we've got access to, but on no other Windows versions.

Update 3: The [previous release](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/releases/tag/1.4.0-beta) of the application is reported to work fine on Windows 7, while the [latest release](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/releases/tag/1.5.0-beta) doesn't. Nothing has changed in the way we build or package the application.

Comment: @Thomas I got a Process Monitor trace from our user. Is it safe to post it here, or does it potentially contains sensitive information?

Comment: Depends on the filters. It may expose paths, IP addresses and even user name. I'd not post a full capture here

Comment: If you right click on the Result column on a line which contains SUCCESS, select "Exclude" from the context menu. This should result in a list of potential problems only.

Comment: A missing DLL problem might be detected by http://debugging.wellisolutions.de/procmonanalyzer/ (although usually a program will crash while yours seems to continue running.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. It's almost certainly not a missing DLL problem as Windows would usually complain about it (missing component etc.) and anyway we've been deploying this software in the wild for many years without issues. I'd vote for some kind of antivirus problem. I can provide you the trace if you're willing to have a look.

Comment: The last event in the problematic trace is "Thread Create", result SUCCESS. There's nothing afterward...

Comment: If you like, you can send it to me at thomas.weller (-(at)-) wellisolutions.de. I'd even sign an NDA if you send one.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a message window somewhere waiting for a mouse click?

Comment: @bvaughn Not that I'm aware of. Note that the problem is only reproducible on our user's machine, to which we don't have access ourselves.

Comment: Hmm. "Current Version: 1.5.0-beta" looks like you still have some work to do. How about adding some trace/debugging code to your beta software? For what it's worth `appleseed.studio.exe` doesn't run here either (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit).

Comment: There *is* tracing and debugging code, the program just hangs before even starting running its own code. (FWIW, we've released 28th versions of this application over the course of 7 years, and we never encountered this problem before.)

Comment: the working computer shows 2 start addresses containing MSVCR120 I do know this is Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable does the not working compyter contain this?

Comment: Yes, the VC runtime is included along with the binaries. The error would also be very different (and completely explicit) if DLLs were missing.

Comment: "It's almost certainly not a missing DLL problem as Windows would usually complain about it (missing component etc.)" - if its a .NET or COM issue it would not.  Have you used Dependency Walker on the program?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, DW shows that dependencies are 100% identical in the previous and new releases of the application...

Comment: You ran DW on the machines where this application isn't working?  I assume you have compared every change between the 28th version and the 29th version?

Comment: Nope, I ran it on my own Windows 10 machine as I don't have access to a Windows 7 one... I'm assuming dependencies are dependencies, regardless of the environment on which they are extracted... Yeah, I've checked the changes that could affect this issue (there are too many changes to check them all in details) and I couldn't find anything suspicious... And bisecting would require having access to a Windows 7 machine/VM...

Comment: @FrançoisBeaune - Come back when you have ran DW on Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't look like a dependency problem. We've spent quite some time investigating this with several people, and it actually looks like a deadlock *in Windows* caused by a component of the Boost programming library. This is all very specific to implementation details of particular Windows and Boost versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this mystery turned out to be the combination of a genuine bug in version 1.61 of the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/) and some implementation details in Windows 7:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12475

The previous release of our application (1.4.0-beta) is using Boost 1.55 and it isn't affected by the bug. The latest release is using Boost 1.61 which has the bug.

Comment: Wow, thanks for finding it. We had a similar issue and I woul've never found it without this hint!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some output when I run it in the Microsoft WinDbg debugger:

```
Break-in sent, waiting 30 seconds...
WARNING: Break-in timed out, suspending.
         This is usually caused by another thread holding the loader lock
(36a4.2fc8): Wake debugger - code 80000007 (first chance)
```

See [StackOverflow what a loader lock is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642/loader-lock-error).

This really happens very early in the startup procedure of the program.

On the callstack I see

```
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0020e9f8 00000000`771eaa78 ntdll!ZwWaitForKeyedEvent+0xa
01 00000000`0020ea00 00000000`771eabe2 ntdll!TppWaitpSet+0x1f1
02 00000000`0020eaa0 00000000`771ed0c4 ntdll!TppSetWaitInterrupt+0xa2
03 00000000`0020eb90 00000000`770bee49 ntdll!RtlRegisterWait+0x1e4
04 00000000`0020ec60 000007fe`d7252e98 kernel32!RegisterWaitForSingleObject+0x59
[...]
MSVCR120!Concurrency::critical_section::lock+0x2a [f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\concrt\rtlocks.cpp @ 1031]
[...]
17 00000000`0020f790 00000000`00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

So this could be (but needn't be) a deadlock: the thread has locked a critical section before and is now waiting for something else. It's hard to say on x64 since getting the arguments is not so easy. Otherwise we could traverse the wait chain.

Comment: It's no wonder why you see "no longer supporting upgrades". It's when I give the finger to "depricated" errors. It's like, oh so you are new to th he club and decided to change compiling and now the world is depricated according to you?!