# How to check that an application runs correctly on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

As an [open source developer](http://appleseedhq.net/), what are my options when it comes to testing my software on a particular version of Windows, in particular on Windows 7 x64?

This is related to my [other question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1124181/program-starts-but-does-nothing-on-windows-7) regarding our open source application mysteriously failing to start on Windows 7 for several users.

Comment: How would you even define “runs correctly”? One thing’s for sure: Tests like those can’t be (fully) automated. Just buy a MSDN subscription and use your favorite virtualization software. That being said, this is sort of “service recommendation”-ish.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm not talking about automated testing. I just want to check why our application doesn't even start on Windows 7. Regarding MSDN: we are a small open source project and we can't afford a MSDN subscription just to investigate an issue once in a while. The question is really rather simple: our app doesn't work on Windows 7, and we don't have a Windows 7 machine to repro the bug. What are our options? Are there MS-sanctioned VM images for Windows 7 x64? (MS has images for Windows 7 x86.)

Comment: @DanielB Are service recommendations frown upon on superuser?

Comment: For what it's worth `appleseed.studio.exe` doesn't run here either (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit).

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for giving it a try! I actually just managed to get my hands on a Windows 7 box and I can reproduce the problem as well. Very mysterious...